# window.print: Receipt printer wasting paper

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I am using wep 800 dx black printer, I have a web app to print receipt. Used window.print() to print the page, when I prints, the printer continues rolling until an A4 page completes. I wanted to stop printing when content of my page ends. No need to waste the paper. Is there any way to stop rolling the page when the data ends?

My page looks like this, and that much blank page prints the printer

```
+-----------------+
|data is here     |
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
+-----------------+
```

I want to stop printing like this

```
+-----------------+
|data is here     |
+-----------------+
```

Comment: What do you mean by `the printer continues rolling until an A4 page completes`. Are you trying to print half a page? Not sure what your intending to do.

Comment: How is this PHP related?

Comment: Updated the question @FabianSchöner

Comment: So just for my understanding: Your website is split onto A4 pages for printing (obviously) and the last page is only halfway filled with content. The A4 page still cant be cut or anything by the printer tho so it continues to roll out a full A4 page which is halfway filled. Dont see any errors right there? Or does it roll out a completely empty page?

Comment: @FabianSchöner update question again

Comment: Dot matrix printers are very rare now, Chromium developers probably see no reason to add special partial-page-print logic that will not work for inkjets and lasers that always must finish the page.  You can try printing to PDF?

Comment: That printer does indeed have a "short tearoff" feature but I doubt it can be invoked directly from javascript. ’window.print()’ does not accept any parameters. I think you will find the only way to exercise detailed control over the printer is via the dialog box offered by the printer's driver.

Comment: What about copying the data to the clipboard instead?  Users can paste into one Word or Wordpad or etc. document and print later.

Comment: @DaveS I'm building a billing software, so users paste into one Word or Wordpad or etc is not possible.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem for printing invoice for a billing app I have created

Comment: Same problem here, could anyone find a Java Script solution? My printer prints every time in A4 with a lot of white after my data at the end.